# Get DropDownList value into POST method

Tags: drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-mvc, http-post

I am working on this `ASP.NET Core MVC` where I have this `DropDownLisit` which gets its values from `Controller` using `ViewBag.DishTypes`. However, upon submitting the form, the `POST` method is not getting the value of the option selected in the `DropDownList`. The code snippets are as follows:

**Controller: GET Method**

```
var allDishTypes = _context.DishType
    .ToList()
    .Select(dt => new SelectListItem { Value = dt.DishTypeId.ToString(), Text = dt.DishTypeName.ToString() }).ToList();

ViewBag.DishTypes = allDishTypes;

return View();
```

**View**

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddMenuItems">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="my-1 mr-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">Dish Type</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="fg-line form-chose">
                <label asp-for="DishTypeId" class="fg-labels" for="DishTypeId">Dish Type</label>
                <select asp-for="DishTypeId" asp-items="ViewBag.DishTypes" class="form-control chosen" data-placeholder="Choose Dish Type" required name="dishtype" id="dishtype">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
             </div>
         </div>
    ....
```

**Controller: POST Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddMenuItems([Bind("DishTypeId, DishName, Cost")] Dishes dishesObj)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> the POST method is not getting the value of the option selected in the DropDownList

Note that you specified a `name=dishtype` within your code. By this way, the field name is 
always the same as this `name` attribute, i.e, `dishtype` instead of `DishTypeId`, which will not be recognized by ASP.NET Core by default.

To fix that issue, simply remove that attribute such that it uses `asp-for` to generate the `name` attribute automatically:

```
<select asp-for="DishTypeId" asp-items="ViewBag.DishTypes" 
    class="form-control chosen" data-placeholder="Choose Dish Type" required 
    name="dishtype" id="dishtype"
>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```